# PDM microphones to Matlab

Tags: beamforming

As a beginner in DSP, I would appreciate your advice and recommendations on building a PCB with eight PDM microphones arranged in a circular distribution. My objective is to connect the PCB to a computer via USB3 and receive raw audio streams from each microphone in Matlab or any processing software, so that I can apply different DSP and beamforming algorithms for audio processing.
Kindly advice do I need PDM to USB transceiver, or any additional IC is required to create this project?

Comment: Welcome to our forum. I think you question would be a better fit  for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Beamforming is sometimes called array processing.  I think once the signal has been digitized, it would be on-topic for Signal Processing (DSP), but how to process the raw electrical signals and filter correctly is probably better for electronics, as stated above.

Comment: Also, they usually like a schematic or circuit diagram on that exchange.

Comment: The EE.SE is OK with questions asking about approaches, but they need to be specific and not "what do I buy?" questions, and you're a bit dangerously on the edge for both (although I'm pretty sure you don't mean to be!): Actually name the microphones. "PDM microphone" tells less than you probably think it does. So, name the device's model name. Then, you really need to define what you mean with "raw audio stream". That also isn't as clear as you probably think it is, and in case of PDM, things might actually become hard to transport even over USB3 if we stick to a specific meaning of *raw*.